# Animation to Remove Sprite

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am currently making a `Sprite` and I want it to *animate before it disappears*.

**For example**: I want it to *animate* it in the sense that it *disappears* from the top of the block until the *bottom*. To put it another way, I want to the size to decrease slowly until there is nothing left. But I want to give it the appearance that it is disappearing rather than scaling to nothing.

```
let hand = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "hand")
hand.size = CGSize(width: size.width/10, height: size.height/30)
hand.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(posX-2)*size.width/10+offsetX, y:CGFloat(posY)*size.height/30+offsetY)
addChild(hand)
```

tl;dr is it possible to make this sort of effect using **SpriteKit** in **Swift**.
Ideal Animation: https://ibb.co/sPsffmK

Comment: As an eraser effect, move an background node over the current node from top to  bottom.

Comment: But what happens if the background is not one solid color. Would it be best practice to “crop” the image (is this even built-in to swift)?

Answer (score 1):

`SKAction` is an animation that is executed by a node in the scene. Actions are used to change a node in some way (like move its position over time), but you can also use actions to change the scene, like doing a fadeout.

In your case, you can apply multiple animations:

```
let move_action = SKAction.moveBy(x: -100, y: 0, duration: 1.0)
let scale_action = SKAction.scale(to: 0.0, duration: 1.0)
let fade_action = SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 0.0, duration: 1.0)

hand.run(move_action)
hand.run(scale_action)
//hand.run(fade_action)
```

In the previous example, the `hand` runs the `move` and `scale` animation at the same time. But you can also make the `hand` to `move` to the `position`, and after it reaches, to `scale` it.

```
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([move_animation,scale_animation])
hand.run(sequence)
```

There are lots of animations that SKAction has, [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/action_initializers) you can find the complete list.